# sysmail_sentitems is not populating even email has been sent.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have sent email using sqlserver database mailing system.
I have received the email in my email address. But it is not saved in sysmail_sentitems.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the following tables

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems

SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_log
```